# C++ Reading a SPECIFIC line from a text file and comparing it with an input

Tags: c++, file

I'm building a login function where the user enters a username. The program should be able to read a text file called "accounts.txt" and read the username line (Which is the 4th line in the text file) and compare the input with the text file's username.

1. User enters username
2. Program reads the 4th line of the text file (i.e: username)
3. Checks if both usernames are the same
4. Success message

How do I get this done, mates?

P.S: fstream is used in this, am I right?

Comment: when you file three issues in the same minute, at least check that the tags you're using make sense. Just because you know the word "Processing" doesn't mean you don't need to first read the explanation text that shows up when you try to use that text. (The 'Processing' tag is for the same-named programming language, which has nothing to do with C++)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is simply to read each line, and only process the ones you are interested about:

```
std::string line;
ifstream login("accounts.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < desired_line; ++i)
   getline(login, line)
getline(login, line);
use_input(line);
```

**Update:**
If the line contains (or begins with) a single integer which represents the id, you can convert it to an integer as such:

```
std::stringstream stream(line);
int id;
stream>>id;
```

Comment: This assumes 0 based indexing for the line numberibgs.

Comment: Your answer is very accurate, but how do you compare the line (which is a string) with my user entered username (which is a int) ?

Comment: @PJ_Boy You can convert it using `std::stringstream`

Comment: A small Example if you please? :)

Comment: I will, but I can't right now. When I get home, ill add an example.

Comment: I've added an example for converting to int.